# shell command to search with device emulation ON in edge browser

Tags: shell, microsoft-edge, device-emulation

I want to search any web page in edge browser having 'device emulation' ON through command line (Not from developer tools like CTRL+SHIFT+M, I want to use shell (or any) command). i.e., I want to search like in the phone but using edge desktop version through command line. How can I do that?

I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, it looks like at present it is not possible to launch the Edge browser with Device emulation using any command.

Device emulation only available if you open the Developer tools.

You manually need to access the Device Emulation feature from the developer tools in the Edge browser.

Same thing applies to ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Is there any programming language to do this?

Comment: At present, it looks like we can't launch Edge browser with the Device emulation using any code approach or using any programming language.