# MS Edge cmd mobile view

Tags: microsoft-edge

I wanna open Microsoft Edge as mobile view from cmd, a tried a lot of parameter but there isn't nothing to do. Can someone help me? There is a parameter to put in code line to open MS Edge as mobile view?

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" https://bing.com/search?q=a --use-mobile-user-agent --profile-directory="Default"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research, it might not be supported to open Microsoft Edge as mobile view from CMD.
Currently, you could manually **toggle device emulation** (Ctrl+Shift+M) in **Developer tools**(F12).

Similar case for reference: [shell command to search with device emulation ON in edge browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74395584/shell-command-to-search-with-device-emulation-on-in-edge-browser#:%7E:text=Based%20on%20my%20research%2C%20it%20looks%20like%20at,from%20the%20developer%20tools%20in%20the%20Edge%20browser.)